# Find an SSL certificate with Powershell that is NOT expired

Tags: powershell

I am struggling with the logic behind finding a certificate that is not expired in Powershell. I have the potential to have multiple certs with the same CN installed, most of them expired, with at LEAST one active, potentially two active for a week or two while manual renewals occur. This is causing me a logic problem that I need help with.

So far, I am able to test with the following certs:

1. FRIENDLYNAME, expires August 10 2024
2. FRIENDLYNAME, expires August 21 2023
3. FRIENDLYNAME, expires August 27 2022

I have the following code working:

```
cd cert:\LocalMachine\my
$today = [DateTime]::Now
get-childitem | where { $_.Subject -match 'CN=FRIEDNLYNAME' -and $_.NotAfter -gt $today }
```

This does accurately return only the non-expired certificate. However, I may have a time when two FRIENDLYNAME certs might be active, and as an example using the above list, number 2 was active for two weeks while number 1 was getting installed.

My logic problem is, how can I have Powershell return only the absolute latest possible expiring cert? I understand the easiest answer is to properly clean up the environments and make sure that only an active cert is installed, but in the event that I cannot do this, how can I make Powershell logic work in my favor?

Comment: Add `| Sort-Object NotAfter | Select-Object -Last 1`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher' | select * | where NotAfter -gt "9/18/2027 1:26:59 PM" | Sort-Object NotAfter | Select-Object -Last 1` returned what I would expect. Are you sure $today contains the value you think it does?

Comment: @SimonS That actually covers what I want, and with that I wouldn't even need the `$_.NotAfter -gt $today` part!

Comment: @Ramhound $today does contain today's date using that function, yeah. The trouble is there might be multiple not-expired certs at a given time, SimonS's comment sorts the results and pulls the last one, meaning the latest expiring cert.

Comment: I assume the certificate is not in some other certificate store other than "My..."?

Comment: The certs will always be in the same store, correct.

Comment: @nightsurfer You don't necessarily need `$_.NotAfter -gt $today`, however I would leave it in there, because if somehow you don't have ANY cert that isn't expired, the NotAfter makes sure that you won't get a return at all in that case. If you take it away an expired cert will be returned

Comment: @SimonS good shout, as this will be part of an automated process that retrieves the thumbprint and utilizes it, I have logic in place already to fail out if a thumbprint isn't found. You can make this an answer and I'll mark it as such, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply sort your output with [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.3) and then pick the last object with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3) and it's `-Last` Parameter.

```
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$Today = [DateTime]::Now
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {
    $_.Subject -match 'CN=FRIEDNLYNAME' -and $_.NotAfter -gt $Today
} | Sort-Object NotAfter | Select-Object -Last 1
```